How to know which filepaths are causing the "file name(s) would be too long for the destination folder" error?
I have the following error when copying files with Windows Explorer:


Destination Path Too Long
The file name(s) would be too long for the destination folder. You can
shorten the file name and try again, or try a location that has a shorter
path.
impl
Date created: 8/5/2022 6:25 PM
Do this for all current items
Skip   Cancel

How to know which filepaths are causing the "file name(s) would be too long for the destination folder" error?

BTW, for some file operations, I use a folder, C\tmp, with an intentionally short path and name. After files are there, I use a tool such as Bulk Rename Utility, https://www.bulkrenameutility.co.uk, or alternatives, https://alternativeto.net/software/bulk-rename-utility/, to shorten and standardize filenames.

I believe current versions of windows still restrict local paths to around 260 characters (some APIs are 256 characters). UNC paths may allow for longer paths.
There is an article from Microsoft which gives details of how to increase this limit: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/maximum-file-path-limitation?tabs=registry
You can use PowerShell to find paths longer than 260 characters:
cmd /c dir /s /b |? {$_.length -gt 260}

Since the error you are getting is on the destination (not the source path) you may need to drop the number down a bit (say 230) to find which path is being copied to the longer destination path.
